# How can one prove that : $V(x,y) = 50x^2 + 100xy + 100y^2 \geq 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I want to ask how can one prove strictly mathematically that the following inequality holds:
$$V(x,y) = 50x^2 + 100xy + 100y^2 \geq 0$$

as I saw by plotting it in *Wolfram Alpha* here : [WA Link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=V(x,y)%20%3D%20(6x%20%2B%2014y)(-x%2B6y)%20%2B%20(14x%20%2B%2016y)(4x%2By))

I guess one can say that due to the "large" coefficients and the squares of the terms $50x^2$ and $100y^2$, the term $10xy$ gets "eliminated" and obviously $V(0,0) = 0$, so $V(x,y) \geq 0$, but that's definitely not a strict proof.

Comment: show that $(0, 0)$ is a global minimum

Comment: Thet's definitely not a proof *at all*, strict or otherwise.

Comment: @KirylPesotski Could work like that, was trying to see if there was a faster way (as it was) and didn't saw it because I'm pretty blind sometimes. Thanks for the heads up !

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I know, I'm pretty sure you can't say anything that this and be even 0.1% eligible. Thanks a lot for the heads up !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is $$50(x^2+2xy+2y^2)=50((x+y)^2+y^2)\geq 0$$

Comment: Bleh I'm blind obviously ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: i hope you are not reelly blind!

Comment: you are from Greek?

Comment: No I'm not, don't worry, sometimes I just don't see obvious stuff. Yes, I'm Greek!

Comment: then you will see the new Akropolis!

Comment: New Acropolis ? Where ?

Comment: in Athen, it will be restaurated

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$=50\left(x+\dfrac y{10}\right)^2+y^2\left(100-\dfrac{50}{10^2}\right)$$